# How to install and start CouchDB server in a Docker image of a Web Application?

Tags: python, docker, server, couchdb

I made a Docker Image of a Web Application which is built on Python and my Web application needs CouchDB server to start before running the programme. Can anyone please tell me how can I install and run CouchDB server in the Dockerfile of this Web Application. My Dockerfile is given below:

```
FROM python:2.7.15-alpine3.7
RUN mkdir /home/WebDocker
ADD ./Webpage1 /home/WebDocker/Webpage1
ADD ./requirements.txt /home/WebDocker/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /home/WebDocker

RUN pip install -r /home/WebDocker/requirements.txt
RUN apk update && \
        apk upgrade && \^M
        apk add bash vim sudo
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I solved it by using [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for running a separate [CouchDB Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb/) and a separate Python Container. The relevant part of the configuration file `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
# This help to avoid routing conflict within virtual machines:
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.112.0/24


# The CouchDB data is kept in docker volume:
volumes:
  couchdb_data:


services:
 # The container couchServer uses Dockerfile from the subdirectory CouchDB-DIR 
 # and it has the hostname 'couchServer':
  couchServer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CouchDB-DIR/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: couchdb_data
        target: /opt/couchdb/data
        read_only: False 
      - type: volume
        source: ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_BASEPATH}/couchdb_log
        target: /var/log/couchdb
        read_only: False
    tty: true
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=__secret__
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
  python_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Python_DIR/Dockerfile
...
```

In the Docker subnet, the CouchDB can be accessed by `http://couchServer:5984` from the Python container. To ensure that the CouchDB is not lost when restarting the container, it is kept in a separate Docker volume `couchdb_data`. 
Use the enviroment-variable `DOCKER_VOLUMES_BASEPATH` to determine in which directory CouchDB logs. It can be defined in a [.env-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

The network section is only necessary if you have routing problems.

Comment: Thank you. As I didn't use it before it's a bit confusing for me. Is it possible to use Supervisor? @Dietrich